# Java's protected doesn't protect

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

Java's `protected` members declared in class are visible in the whole package. Why?

I simply want to share privacy between my class and it's subclasses but Java doesn't allow me.

What I am supposed to do?

Comment: Please post your code, how are you declaring these fields or methods?

Comment: Live with the way java access modifiers work.

Comment: See [this table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052) for a clear description of the scope of protected. *Why* the semantics of protected was implemented this way can most likely only be answered by the designers of the language.

Comment: Which part of tutorial/documentation makes you think that it should behave differently?

Answer (score 1):

`protected` are sharing also between package members, so you could move your class and its children to a separate package.

Answer (score 0):

`protected` Members are Visible to the `package` and **all subclasses** (protected). So, Why so surprised ? .

Answer (score 0):

This is its intended behavior. All fields that are declared as `protected` are visible within the class, the package and all subclasses, including those outside the package.